# Draggable + sortable menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a simple menu with categories, I want these categories to be draggable and sortable. The code is:

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 12px;">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: left;">
                    <b>Category name</b>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
                    <b>Products</b>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center">
                    <b>Popularity</b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div id="sortable">
            {% for category in categories %}
                <div class="row" class="draggable" style="border: 1px solid silver; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220)">
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="height: 35px;">
                        {{ category.id }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center; height: 40px;">
                        {{ category.product_count}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center; height: 40px;">
                        {{ category.popularity|default(0) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is it doesn't work. When I use id instead of a class as a draggable element, only the first element can be moved...and it is not sorted. When it looks like right now, so when I use a class, nothing works. jQuery code is:

```
$('#sortable').sortable();
            $('.draggable').draggable({
                connectToSortable: "#sortable"
            });
```

What happens, why is that so? Thanks!

Comment: When you use id the query selector only return the first matched element only thats why.

Comment: Why doesnt it work when I use class then?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('#sortable').sortable(
{
   items: ".draggable"
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer.